# Erlang - undefined function

Tags: function, exception, erlang, export

I'm trying to execute a very simple Erlang code, and it's not working.
I've tryied executed some hello worlds without problem, but not mine own code.

```
-module(server).
%% Exported Functions
-export([start/0, process_requests/1]).
%% API Functions
start() ->
    ServerPid = spawn(server, process_requests, [[]]),
    register(myserver, ServerPid).
process_requests(Clients) ->
    receive
         {client_join_req, Name, From} ->
         NewClients = [From|Clients],  %% TODO: COMPLETE
            broadcast(NewClients, {join, Name}),
            process_requests(NewClients);  %% TODO: COMPLETE
        {client_leave_req, Name, From} ->
            NewClients = lists:delete(From, Clients),  %% TODO: COMPLETE
            broadcast(Clients, {leave, Name}),  %% TODO: COMPLETE
            process_requests(NewClients);  %% TODO: COMPLETE
        {send, Name, Text} ->
            broadcast(Clients, {message, Name, Text}),  %% TODO: COMPLETE
            process_requests(Clients)
end.
%% Local Functions
broadcast(PeerList, Message) ->
    Fun = fun(Peer) -> Peer ! Message end,
    lists:map(Fun, PeerList).
```

Compile result:

```
5> c(server).
    {ok,server}
6> server:start().       
** exception error: undefined function server:start/0
```

Comment: Works fine here: `Eshell V5.8.5  (abort with ^G)
1> c(server).
{ok,server}
2> server:start().
true
3>`

Comment: How to download a previous version on eshell?

Comment: I don't think the version is the problem.  I get the same result on the latest Erlang available (R15B01, Eshell V5.9.1).  What platform are you on?

Comment: Mac OS X, mountain lion.

Comment: @user1573607 Are you sure you are compiling and loading the version of server.erl you think you are. I know it sounds stupid but it **is** an easy error to mistake. Try doing `m(server).` in the shell to see which file has been loaded.

Comment: to just complete what [rvirding](http://stackoverflow.com/users/77617/rvirding) said I suggest you also use `server:module_info()` it pretty much shows the same that `m(server)` but displays the location of the source file instead of the bean file.

Comment: `server:module_info().
[{exports,[{module_info,0},{module_info,1}]},
 {imports,[]},
 {attributes,[{vsn,[135950385919026767954855850574369266097]}]},
 {compile,[{options,[]},
           {version,"4.8.2"},
           {time,{2012,9,26,18,50,48}},
           {source,"/Users/.../server.erl"}]}]`

Comment: Fixed! It was the text editor. Don't know why but writing the same, SMULTRON creates a non valid beam file.

Answer (score 2):

You compile you code with `c/1`, but you forgot to load it to VM with `l/1`.  While VM does loads modules **new** automatically (modules not yet loaded to VM), it doesn't reload them each time you compile to new beam.

If you do it a lot in development you might want to look into tools like [sync](https://github.com/rustyio/sync).

Answer (score 1):

Try to check with pwd(). whether you are in the directory where your listed server code is. Seems to be a path issue. It also can happen that in your code:get_path() there is a directory where another server.beam is sitting that has not got a start function.